# "open in IE 1.4" addon stopped working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Whenever I press on the *open in IE* icon, I get an error in the console:
Error: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIProcess.init]
Source File: chrome://openinie/content/openinie.js
Line: 126 (This happened ever since upgrade to 16.0 and I assume it's probably security related)

I found that js file to be **inside** some "openinie@wittersworld.com.xpi" file (which I cleverly renamed to zip), and saw the offending line:

```
    var iePath = openinie.getIEPath();

    // create an nsILocalFile for the executable
    var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
    file.initWithPath(iePath);

    // create an nsIProcess
    var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
    process.init(file);  // <-line 126
```

1. is it possible to fix it and "re-compile" it zipping and renaming?
   (I assume it's something with security maybe).
2. can I debug this using for example an alert box to display values of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to fix it and "re-compile" it zipping and renaming

Yes, you can simply replace a file in the ZIP archive, most extensions aren't signed (you can remove the `META-INF` directory from the XPI file if this one is). In fact, for your debugging it is better to unpack `openinie@wittersworld.com.xpi` into a directory named `openinie@wittersworld.com` in the same folder and remove the original file - this way you won't need to pack/unpack on each change. You should also start Firefox with the `-purgecaches` command line parameter, otherwise the file you are changing might get cached.

> can I debug this using for example an alert box to display values of variables?

Yes. However, I would rather recommend [`Components.utils.reportError()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Components.utils.reportError) that will log to the Error Console (press Ctrl-Shift-J to open it) without opening modal dialogs. In this particular case I would write:

```
Components.utils.reportError(iePath);
```

This seems to point to a non-existent file meaning that the `getIEPath()` function is faulty.

Good luck!

Comment: OK thanks I'll use it. btw: I fixed the error using the add-on's option to point to the external program (ie). indeed the path for some reasons was wrong.